# Error when using dateadd with millesecond in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, dateadd

Recently there is an issue from my side.

In the table in redshift I have 2 columns:

The visit_time, which mentions the start time of the session and in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format; Another column which is the time_spent, and it stands for the millesecond that user spends in certain page and currently it is in float(8)

What I want to do is to Add the visit_time with time_spent in second and convert it into YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, for example 2018-09-20 21:00:55 + 2 = 2018-09-20 21:00:57, so that I can get the visit_end_time. I tried to add it with date add function like this

```
Select     
dateadd(SECOND,CAST (a.timeonpage AS DECIMAL)/1000 ,a.visit_time::date) time_left,
```

But it returns error: Invalid operation: function pg_catalog.date_add("unknown", double precision, date) does not exist

To do this, I tried to used the dateadd function like this:

```
Select     
dateadd(SECOND,CAST (a.timeonpage AS INTEGER)/1000 ,a.visit_time::date) time_left,
```

It does not return error, but it returns the start of the date e.g  2018-09-23 00:00:00, which is not sth that I need.

What is the error that I made and how can I solve it? 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The dateadd function does require an integer for the interval. The problem with your second example is that when you cast `a.visit_time` to a date type it truncates it to the start of that day (removes the time component). Cast it to a timestamp instead:

```
select dateadd(second, round(a.timeonpage/1000.0)::integer, a.visit_time::timestamp);

select dateadd(second, round(2345/1000.0)::integer, '2018-09-20 21:00:55'::timestamp);
      date_add
---------------------
 2018-09-20 21:00:57
```

Also if you are storing visit_time as a string I would recommend making the column type a timestamp.